# IOS Core Data error when subtracting and multiplying in coredata predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an application that deals with user location

my code is

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DoctorTable" inManagedObjectContext:[myData managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


passedLat = @"32.067288";
passedLng = @"33.325347";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:

                          @"( ( ((%f  -  lat) * (%f  -  lat)) + ((%f - lng) * (%f - lng)) ) <  %f)"
                          " and kind  == 0"

                          , passedLat.doubleValue, passedLat.doubleValue, passedLng.doubleValue, passedLng.doubleValue, [self calcDist:DoctorDistance], nil];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

The problem is the first section in the predicate which is

```
@"( ( ((%f  -  lat) * (%f  -  lat)) + ((%f - lng) * (%f - lng)) ) <  %f)"
```

is always true no matter the passedlat or paessedlng
i also tried to replace it with

```
 @"(((2-2)*(3-3)) <> 0)"
```

this also evaluates to true

also note that [self calcDist:DoctorDistance] returns 0.00005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicates used in Core Data fetch requests do not handle parentheses correctly. By setting the launch argument ***"-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3"*** one can see that your last example predicate

```
@"(((2-2)*(3-3)) <> 0)"
```

is translated to the SQL query

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, ... FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE ? - ? * ? - ? <> ? 
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 2
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = 2
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = 3
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[3] = 3
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[4] = 0
```

which means that the parentheses are ***ignored*** and the predicate

```
@"2 - 2 * 3 - 3 <> 0"
```

is used instead. This seems to be a Core Data bug and does not happen if you use the
predicate for example with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`.

As a workaround, you can expand all parentheses in your predicate:

```
@"%f * %f - 2 * %f * lat + lat * lat + %f * %f - 2 * %f * lng + lng * lng < %f", ...
```

Then you should get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are squaring the differences between coordinates, but comparing with an simple distance value.

I recommend to do your calculations outside the predicate.

```
float passedLat = 32.067288;
float passedLng = 33.325347;

float distance = [self calcDist:DoctorDistance]; 
float lowerLat = passedLat - distance; 
float upperLat = passedLat + disstance;
float lowerLng = passedLng - distance;
float upperLng = passedLng + distance; 

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: 
        @"(lat < %f && lat > %f) && (lng < %f && lng > %f)", 
         upperLat, lowerLat, upperLng, lowerLng];
```

.

*NB: Of course you are aware that this is only an approximation of the distance, as the earth is not a flat surface but a centrifugal ellipsoid.*

Comment: Thanks, Actually I am converting code from Android to iOS, that means I can't change the way of calculation even your provided answer is better. Also [self calcDist:DoctorDistance] returns like the square of the distance

Comment: Yes, you can. I do it all the time. The desire to use logic code 1:1 is understandable but should have its limits.